# Is it possible to fill in this region of mesh using modifiers?

Tags: edit-mode

I have a rather untidy mesh in which I would like to fill in as shown attached.

The cross sectioned highlighted with blue lines is a tapered hole that I would like to fill in somehow so that the resulting outer surfaces of the new mesh would be flush with the area marked with black lines?

The 2nd picture just shows the density of edges on the inner red line.

Is there some function I can attempt to use?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Select both edge loops and use "bridge edge loops" operation.  You won't get good topology, but from the looks of it, you're not worried about topology right now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I attempted the select edge loops, somehow it doesn't work. Maybe Blender doesn't know where to go? I will try to select manually. Modifiers are not mandatory.

Comment: I expanded my answers, you'll have to play around with various selects and Shift-Select to accumulate the inside (and outside) edges.  Select > Similar > Amount of Faces Around an Edge ... may work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the word "Modifiers" in your title; is the use of Modifiers mandatory for an answer?

I would instead:

1. for the inner mesh (to continue as a hole), select an edge and then Select > Edge Loops.  Or you may have to play around with Select > Similar > Amount of Faces Around an Edge, and perhaps use ctl:RMB to eliminate your outer grouping.   Or try other Select (like Select > Circle, and slowly add edges).   Once you have the correct edges, I would create a vertex group in case you need to select these again.

[image]

Then extrude these to match the desired depth of your hole.

[image]

2. keeping those selected Shift-LMB select in addition an edge on the outer surface and then use Edge > Bridge Edge Loops.

[image]

Comment: This looks promising and exactly what I need especially creating the vertex group. Thanks!

Comment: How do I create a vertex group from the selected edges? There are no options via RMB. The option vertex groups -> assign to new group doesn't do anything.

Comment: I have it. One can do it via the "object data properties" on the bottom right corner. I have one final query. You mentioned something about extrude up to a certain point. How is this done. You removed this tip from your initial comment. Thanks

Comment: @user9106985 -- once you have the "inner hole" edges selected in Edit Mode, just type 'e' for extrude, or click on "Extrude Region" on the left side transform buttons.